# Distance between centriod of the polygon and each and every point of the polygon

Tags: python, polygon, geometry, distance, geopandas

[image]I'm trying to calculate the distance between centriod of the polygon and each and every point of the polygon using GeoPandas Python

I need to find the distance between centroid(18.9568383649  72.831281) and geometry POLYGON ((72.83164071429999 18.9568102857, 
                                    72.8314213636 18.9569958182, 72.831512 
                                   18.9569766667,72.83164071429999 
                                   18.9568102857))

How I can find the distance? I'm not tied to using GeoPandas.

Comment: Do you know the formula for computing the distance between two points? If not, look up Euclidean distance. Then you can just loop through all your polygon vertices and apply that formula. I would also reproject your polygon to a CRS in meters, as computing distances with lon/lats is almost always wrong.

Comment: yes  I know the formula but the here I have used haversine as they are geospatial data , I'm looking for something which will give me the distance between centroid and each and every point of the polygon in python

Comment: If you know the formula, why can't you apply it? Can you add more details to your question to let us know where you're having issues?

Comment: sure, if my dataframe has cenlat=18.8989 ,centlong=72.8989, lat=19.78979, long=73.87897     i know I'm going to apply this formula df['distance']= df[['cenlat', 'lat', 'cenlong', 'lon']].apply(lambda x: \
                            math.acos(np.sin(x[0]* np.pi/180)*np.sin(x[1]*np.pi/180)+ \
                            np.cos(x[0]*np.pi/180)*np.cos(x[1]*np.pi/180)*np.cos((x[2]-x[3])*np.pi/180))* 6371000 , axis=1)  but if my dataframe contains values like a polygon list how should I proceed? please refer the image for your reference

Comment: Geopandas stores your polygons as shapely objects. You can access them with gdf.geometry.values[0] to get the first one. Then, you can use the .coords() and .xy() methods to access the values of each point of the polygon. See the shapely user manual: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html